# Setting values in controller for Create and Update (RoR 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm learning RoR Through Mickael Hartl's tutorial ...

While creating or updating a record (my application's parameter definition) in my parameters_controller, I need to add data from the session cookie. So I added this code in my controller :

```
private
def current_user
  remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end
```

and this code in my create function to setup some fields automatically from session data :

```
def create
  @parameter = Parameter.new(parameter_params) #code generated by Rails
  @parameter.updated_by = current_user.name    #my additional code
  @parameter.created_by = current_user.name
  respond_to do |format|
    if @parameter.save
    ...
```

Which works fine, but it does not work with the update function :

```
def update      
  @parameter.updated_by = current_user.name        #my additional code
  respond_to do |format|                           #code generated by Rails
    if @parameter.update(parameter_params)         
    ...
```

just does nothing.

Can someone explain me what I missed ?

Thanks a lot !

Best regards,

Fred

Comment: Create and update both are different things, create method creates new object in database but update method update the existing object.
So while updating any record you have to pass specific object to update method.

Comment: Can you post your update form and request parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your @parameter first.  Something like,

```
@parameter= Parameter.find(params[:id])
```

Once, you retrieve the object, you can update it's attributes.

Comment: Great and simple ! I like it ! Thanks !